# Java Localized text Web services using ResourceBundle(locale.properties)

Tags: java, web-services, localization, resourcebundle

There is a functionality which due to some reasons has been moved from the web application to Web services. On web application side we used FMT tags to retrieve the localized text and it used to work fine. Now i need to implement the same on Web service application. For Implementing this i thought of using ResourceBundle Class, however since the web services are stateless i do not want to invoke the 
`ResourceBundle.getBundle(filename)`

As it may invoke a IO operation everytime a web service call i invoked. Instead since my locale keys are not enormous i thought of loading all the ResourceBundles in a singleton Map and pass the key and get the bundle kind of approach.

There are  questions to this:
a.) is this approach fine?
b.) How do i load all the locales using resourcebundle in my singleton map, i.e. is there a way i can load all the locale files mentioned in the locale folder without mentioning each file's name explicitly.

Appreciate any help in advance.

Rgards,

Vaibhav

Answer (score 2):

First things first: I would never never ever make my web-services "locale aware". Showing localized messages to the users it's the caller's job. The web-service is a backend component and doesn't care about language, no more than it cares about screen resolutions. But anyway...

...if I were in NO position of bargaining about my web-services being "i18n aware" I would load each bundle file in a [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) object, then put all those objects in a Map and make it available in the application's context.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just as Daniel pointed out, it really makes sense to create locale-agnostic web service. The best way is to only return Identifiers (for example resource key names) and resolve them to appropriate messages on the client side.

However, if you access the code with JavaScript, the method described above could not really be used and you need actual translations.
In that case, you need to build some access layer to the actual resource files. It could be done with [WeakHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) and loading resource files on demand.

To make it clear what I mean, I think you need something along these lines:

```
public class ResourceLayer {
    private final WeakHashMap<Locale, ResourceBundle> cache =
                      new WeakHashMap<>();

    public String getString(String key, Locale locale) {
        ResourceBundle resources = cache.get(locale);

        if (resources == null) {
            resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BASE_NAME, locale);
            cache.put(locale, resources);
        }

        try {
            return resources.getString(key);
        } catch (MissingResourceException mre) {        
            logger.error("The translation for " + key
                    + " is missing for locale " + locale.toLanguageTag());
            // Visually indicate an error
            return "!" + key + "!";
        }
    }
}
```

Few points to make here. The WeakHashMap will retain the files as long as they are needed, so it should not impact memory footprint much. The [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) you will read in this example, are actually the instances of [PropertyResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html) class. You may want to check it out, but actual implementation reads the properties file all at once and backs it in the HashMap. Therefore you will hit I/O operation only with the first access to given language resource.
It is some kind of compromise between memory consumption and the disk usage, so you may want to pre-load stuff for commonly used languages...

Last, but not least. I didn't really recommend the solution, but you can actually put resources into the database (which will hurt Localizability) and read it on demand.

Comment: Does makes a lot of sense, indeed localization at Web Services level is a big NO, but this is a custom case of a specific application and hence i was left for lesser choices. Appriciate your response on the same,